# phalcon relationship return false

Tags: php, model, foreign-keys, phalcon

i want to create relationship between users table and product table but the result returns false 
this is user model :

```
class Users extends \Phalcon\Mvc\Model
{
public $id;
public $name;
public $password;
 public $email;

 public function initialize()
    {
        $this->setSchema("asulaiman");
        $this->setSource("users");

        $this->hasMany(
            'id',
            'Products',
            'product_id'
        );}}
```

and this is my product model :

```
class Products extends \Phalcon\Mvc\Model
{
    public $id;
    public $user_id;
    public $name;

    public function initialize()
    {
        $this->setSchema("asulaiman");
        $this->setSource("products");

         $this->belongsTo(
            'product_id',
            'Users',
            'id'
        );}}
```

and this query :

```
public function showAction($id)
{
    $get_product = Products::findFirst('id = ' . $id);
    if (!empty($get_product)) {
        $this->response->setJsonContent(array('data' => $get_product->users));
return $this->response; 
}}
```

this result returns :
[image]

Any help please

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is what happens when no relationship is found.

I'm going to assume your users have many products and those products belong to the users. What your code on the Products model is saying is the `products_id` field on the `Products` model relates to the `id` field on the `User` model.

The problem is that there is no `product_id` field on the `Products` model.

```php
 $this->belongsTo(
    'user_id' // "id" field on the Products model
    'Users', // The model I want
    'id'// The field I want on that model (Users.id)
);
```

What you're doing doesn't really make a lot of sense. Besides explaining how the relationships work, I can't really help you any further without seeing the schema.

Comment: products model has 3 columns ( id , name , user_id ) the ( user_id ) column is a foreign key for Users model .. and Users model has 4 columns ( id , name , password , email ) only

Comment: Then you'll want your `belongsTo` relationship to look like the code example in my answer.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you are trying to retrive the property users of a product: $get_product->users But products have no users (only id, user_id and name);

First you have to retrive the user_id:

```
$product = Products::FindFirstById($id);
$user = Users::FindFirstById($product->user_id);
```

You can also do that in one step but it's clearer this way.

Comment: i want to access columns in users table by ( user_id ) foreign key .. and the relationship name is users

Comment: The variable $user contains the User object that is related with the product you want to show.